# Instantiating a native object that takes another object by reference in C++/CLR

Tags: c#, c++, boost

I have an unmanaged C++ project that I wish to use in a C# project.I have built a DLL out of it exporting a class (started with just a class to try).
I want to wrap this class using C++/CLR but I have never done this before and I am having a problem.The class constructor takes a boost object of type io_service by reference and I do not know how I can replicate this in  C++/CLR project and have it work.Below is my code and the error that occurs when I pass the boost object like it was done in the unmanaged code.

//agent.h

`agent(boost::asio::io_service &service)` //this is how the constructor was declared in the       unmanaged code

//agentWrapper.h

```
namespace agentWrapper 
{

public ref class ManagedAgent
{

private:
    agent* m_agent;
public:
    ManagedAgent();

    ~ManagedAgent();

};
}
```

//agentWrapper.cpp

namespace agentWrapper
{
         boost::asio::io_service service;

```
     ManagedAgent::ManagedAgent()
     {
         m_agent=new agent(boost::asio::io_service &service);

     }
     ManagedAgent::~ManagedAgent()
     {
     delete m_agent;
     }
}
```

When I try to run this, I get the error:

`Error  12  error C2275: 'boost::asio::io_service' : illegal use of this type as an expression  agent_Wrapper.cpp   1   17`

Does anyone with good knowledge in wrapping C++ code know how I can instantiate this native class in the wrapper code.Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your constructor call looks like a declaration.  It is so out of whack that I can't guess what you intended.  You do need to get the basic native C++ syntax correct first.  Best guess is that you also need to add a `boost::asio::io_service* service` member to the class.  And of course keep in mind that the C# code can never give you one.

Comment: I understand what you mean,i actually didn't write the code for the native class but i have to use it and that is why i have to wrap it.I also just found out that i was doing something wrong,in the wrapper project i am supposed to instatiate the native class meaning i should call the constructor and pass a service object.Instead i was kind  of like re-declaring the constructor.I have now changed it and now i only have linking errors about the calling convention.I think if i solve the errors it will work okay.Thanks anyway.